# Почему константный метод может вызвать неконстантный метод члена класса?

Tags: c++

В коде ниже константный метод класса `B` вызывает неконстантный метод своего члена `A &a_ref`, что, казалось бы, противоречит логике `const` квалификатора (по идее код не должен компилироваться). Почему, собственно, так происходит?

[Минимальный код](http://cpp.sh/7nsbz):

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    void NonConstHello() /*const*/
    {
        std::cout << "non const Hello from A!" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    A &a_ref;

    explicit B(A &a) : a_ref(a) {}
    void ConstHello() const /*const method*/
    {
        a_ref.NonConstHello();  // calls non-const method for his member???
        std::cout << "    const Hello from B!" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b(a);
    b.ConstHello();
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
non const Hello from A!
    const Hello from B!
```

Comment: тут ответ состоит из одного предложения.  Обьект, содержащий ссыльку, после вызова  метода(константного) всеравно ссылается на тот же обьект, и как бы последный не изменил свое состояние, первый все также ссылается на него(обьекту `В` не интересует что делает обьект `А`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### В приведённом коде нет вызова неконстантного метода у константного объекта

Код из вопроса эквивалентен следующему:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    void NonConstHello() /*const*/
    {
        std::cout << "non const Hello from A!" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B
{
public:
// pointer instead of reference
    A *a_ptr;

    explicit B(A *a) : a_ptr(a) {}
    void ConstHello() const /*const method*/
    {
        (*a_ptr).NonConstHello();
        std::cout << "    const Hello from B!" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b(&a);
    b.ConstHello();
    return 0;
}
```

Причём эквивалентен как функционально, так и по определению ссылки.

Разберёмся, что тут происходит с `const`-квалификатором.

Константность метода класса `B` означает, что все его члены становятся константными, как значения, то есть указатель становится константным, получая тип `A * const` (а не `const A*`!).

Это значит, что мы не можем из этого метода менять указатель как адрес, данные же легально можно менять, вызов неконстантного метода происходит не у члена класса, а у результата его разыменования.

Оператор разыменования является константным (он не может изменять адрес) и возвращает **неконстантную** ссылку на объект, к которому мы легально применяем неконстантный метод.

---

**Вернёмся к исходному примеру со ссылкой.**

Теперь всё становится ясно. Ссылка это, если очень грубо, "указатель, неявно приводящийся к объекту там, где это необходимо". Вызов метода у ссылки на самом деле это не вызов метода ссылки, а вызов метода объекта, размещённого по соответствующему адресу.

Константность метода `B` запрещает нам менять член, который является ссылкой (то есть менять её адрес), но менять данные, на которые ссылка указывает нам не воспрещено, что мы успешно и делаем, вызывая неконстантный метод.

Грубо говоря, `a_ref` в константном методе класса `B` имеет тип не `const A&`, а `A & const` (справедливости ради заметим, что ссылку нельзя менять в любом случае, она лишь один раз инициализируется, и больше её адрес неизменен, по сути она итак как адрес константная).

Comment: может быть я не прав, но  считаю, что  ответ слышком многословен для данного вопроса, и тут ничего "грубо говоря" не нужно _  ответ тут однозначен: ссылька не константная, значит можно изменять обьект по ссыльке

Comment: *"`a_ref` в константном методе класса `B` имеет тип не `const A&`, а `A & const`"* Нет, тип остается `A &`. Ссылки константными не бывают.

Comment: ссылька на константный  обьект ,  часто выражают как "константная ссылька "(для краткости)